# Add var in auth

Tags: laravel, authentication, view

I use stard auth from Laravel but I want to send var to auth's view. Actually I want to send title of website and keywords. In other controllers I can do that

```
return view('my.view')->with('title', 'My funny title');
```

How I can do that in Login, Register...

Comment: Same as any other blade you can modify layouts.app file and accept variables and then pass variable from login and register blade.

Comment: share code for `Login, Register` view ?

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you should do something like this.

in your controller( you will find this controller in AuthenticatesUsers Traits located in Illuminate\Foundation\Auth folder.

```
    $title= "my page title";
    return view('my.view', compact('title'));
```

and in view, just use {{ $title }} where ever you cant to call that text. this should work.

Comment: He is saying `In other controllers I can do that`, so now `How I can do that in Login, Register` ? Means code above is working

Comment: Inside `vendor` folder ? It's not recommend

Comment: @C2486 Yup, inside vendor

Answer (score 0):

Add this on baseController/Controller  __construct() function 
by this you will share the variable to every blade file.

```
$siteTitle = 'SiteTitle';
View::share($siteTitle);
```

Comment: It is better to use `session(['siteTitle','Site Title']);` in this case

Comment: Yes but view:sahre and view::composer have a lot of extra functionality Please have a look: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with this syntax as [in documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#passing-data-to-views)

`return view('my.view', ['title' => 'My funny title']);`

or

```
$data = [
  'title' => 'My funny title',
  ...
];
return view('my.view', $data);
```

I remember having the similar issues while ago, though i cant remember how exactly i worked it out.